# XElement over WCF - strange error

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-xml

One of my WCF service is returning a XElement object. Visual Studio, the client web app, is keeping showing this message

`Cannot convert source type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement[Service.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral]' to target type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElemnet[System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]'`

above this piece of code

```
XElement xml = xmlService.Get();
```

Both apps are on the same computer. The project compiles just fine,no error is shown,but it's anoying. What could be the problem ?

BTW Should I rather return a string and the parse it ?

Comment: The whole point of webservices is that you don't have to go into the bowels of the system and fiddle around with and parse XML... why don't you pass well defined objects (and let the runtime handle all the (de)serialization details)??

Comment: It makes sense what you are saying about sending string and parsing it, but what about the error ? XElement implemensts  IXmlSerializable.

Comment: Check that your serivce reference reuses System.Xml.Linq assembly.

Comment: Yes I have the System.Xml.Linq assembly referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After computer restart, it works fine again.